# Firefox 3.5.2 on Ubuntu Jaunty

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

How should I go about getting Firefox 3.5.2 installed on Jaunty, are there any semi-official places I can pull a deb from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the [Ubuntu documentation FirefoxNewVersion page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirefoxNewVersion).

> When a new version of Firefox comes out, there is some delay until it can be downloaded and run. This page will explain how to install Firefox as soon as possible.

Follow the **Instructions for the impatient** that give
**Jaunty** and **Karmic** installation instructions for **firefox 3.5**.

> Low difficulty, high safety: these packages are maintained and fully tested by the Ubuntu Project

Comment: yeah sudo apt-get firefox-3.5 seems to do the trick

Comment: You can also change /usr/bin/firefox to link to firefox-3.5 instead of firefox-3.0 by doing "sudo rm /usr/bin/firefox; sudo ln -s /usr/bin/firefox-3.5 /usr/bin/firefox", though updates to the firefox-3.0 package tend to undo the link.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-3.5
```

Comment: It's 3.5 RC2, not 3.5.1 in the repos.

Comment: this post is also old and he asked for 3.5

Comment: updated the version to 3.5.2 on the question so it remains relevant ..

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 3.5 codenamed "Shiretoko" is available on Ubuntu right now. It's unbranded and not final yet, but works ok for me.

The package name is "firefox-3.5", but it will install alongside firefox 3.0, not upgrade it.