# How do I install firefox 3.5 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox 3.5.2 on Ubuntu Jaunty](https://superuser.com/questions/4993/firefox-3-5-2-on-ubuntu-jaunty)

I want to install firefox 3.5 in ubuntu. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Read this tutorial:

[How to Download & Install Firefox 3.5 On Ubuntu Linux](http://www.blogsdna.com/3824/how-to-download-install-firefox-35-on-ubuntu-904-linux.htm)

Here is the link on Mozilla.org with downloads for all language and operating versions: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html

Answer (score 1):

I personally try to avoid to add too much lines in my sources.list, specially to get the latest version of a software, so, I suggest you to [simply download the latest version of Firefox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/fr/firefox/), extract it to an "Applications" folder in your home directory and just add an icon in your toolbar pointing to that program.

So, it won't mess up when you'll upgrade to next version of Ubuntu (remember, it's every 6 months), you will just have to delete that folder and then, use the Firefox from Ubuntu which will be 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Its there in the repos.

```
sudo aptitude install firefox3.5
```

Simple!

Adding directly from the repos is far better than trying any unnecessary hacks.

But if U want to constantly get updated that version of firefox to daily builds, U could add a few more repos to /etc/src

Comment: The repos contain RC2, not the final build.